# glitch in showing matplotlib pie chart in QGridLayout

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pie-chart

I have a `QGridLayout` which consists of a few `QVBoxLayout`.

Inside each `QVBoxLayout`, first, there is a `QHBoxLayout` consisting of two `QLabel`s, then a matploilib `Figure` that is showing a `pie` chart. The code is something like this:

```
self.canvas_uv254f = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100) 
self.layout_uv254f_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
self.layout_uv254f = QVBoxLayout(self)

self.label_uv254f_parameter = QLabel(self)
self.label_uv254f_unit = QLabel(self)

self.layout_uv254f_parameter.addWidget(self.label_uv254f_parameter)
self.layout_uv254f_parameter.addWidget(self.label_uv254f_unit)
self.layout_uv254f.addLayout(self.layout_uv254f_parameter)
self.layout_uv254f.addWidget(self.canvas_uv254f)
```

and `PieCanvas`:

```
class PieCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):

def __init__(self, width=2, height=2, dpi=100):
    fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi, tight_layout=True)
    self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    super(PieCanvas, self).__init__(fig)
```

Then I add these layouts to my `QGridLayout` as following:

```
self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_uv254f.layout(), 2, 1)
```

everything is fine by adding `layout`s in these positions:

> (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)

But, when I add a `layout` in  (0, 3) ( or (1, 3), or both of them), a highlight of the `pie` chart is shown between 3rd and 4th columns.

[image]

This glitch may disappear if I resize the application size with the mouse manually, however, it is not the solution!

Any ideas of what the problem?

python and libraries:

- matplotlib 3.2.2
- PyQt5
- python 3.6.9

**minimal reproducible example**

```
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.tab_widget = MyTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.show()


class MyTabWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.myFont = QtGui.QFont()
        self.myFont.setBold(True)

        # creating a tab bar
        self.tab = TabWidget()

        # data-frames to store various parts of data-frame
        self.new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.new_df = self.prepare_data()

        # widgets associated with each tab
        self.online_data_tab = QWidget()

        # assigning tabs to tab bar
        self.tab.addTab(self.online_data_tab, "Dashboard")

        # --------------------------------------------          dashboard tab

        self.canvas_csbeq = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_no3 = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_temperature = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_farbe = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_ph = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_cod = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_afseq = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_uv254t = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_csbfeq = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)
        self.canvas_uv254f = PieCanvas(width=2, height=2, dpi=100)

        # layout fr each gauge
        self.layout_CSBeq = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_temp = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_no3 = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_farbe = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_ph = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_cod = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_afseq = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_uv254t = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_uv254f = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_csbfeq = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # labels for parameters' names and units
        self.layout_csbeq_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_temp_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_ph_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_no3_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_farbe_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_cond_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_afseq_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_uv254t_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_uv254f_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout_csbfeq_parameter = QHBoxLayout(self)

        # labels for units and parameter names

        self.label_parameter_csbeq = QLabel(self)
        self.label_unit_csbeq = QLabel(self)
        self.label_temp_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_temp_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_ph_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_ph_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_no3_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_no3_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_farbe_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_farbe_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_cond_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_cond_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_afseq_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_afseq_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_uv254t_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_uv254t_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_uv254f_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_uv254f_unit = QLabel(self)
        self.label_csbfeq_parameter = QLabel(self)
        self.label_csbfeq_unit = QLabel(self)

        self.draw_gauge()

        self.online_data_tab.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_CSBeq.layout(), 0, 0)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_csbfeq.layout(), 1, 0)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_temp.layout(), 2, 0)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_ph.layout(), 0, 1)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_no3.layout(), 1, 1)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_uv254f.layout(), 2, 1)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_farbe.layout(), 0, 2)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_cod.layout(), 1, 2)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_afseq.layout(), 0, 3)
        self.online_data_tab.layout.addLayout(self.layout_uv254t.layout(), 1, 3)
        self.online_data_tab.setLayout(self.online_data_tab.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tab)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.tab.resize(150, 96)
        self.tab.show()

    def draw_gauge(self):
        data_csbeq = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[6]].iloc[0]  # 6 = csbeq
        data_temp = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[14]].iloc[0]  # 14 = temperature
        data_no3 = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[4]].iloc[0]  # 4 = no3-k mg/l
        data_farbe = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[15]].iloc[0]  # 15 = farbe blau
        data_ph = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[16]].iloc[0]  # 16 = pH
        data_cod = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[17]].iloc[0]  # 17 = cod µS/cm
        data_afseq = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[2]].iloc[0]  # 2 = afseq
        data_uv254t = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[10]].iloc[0]  # 10 = uv254t
        data_uv254f = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[12]].iloc[0]  # 10 = uv254f
        data_csbfeq = self.new_df.loc[:, self.new_df.columns[8]].iloc[0]  # 10 = csbfeq

        data_csbeq_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_csbeq.axes.pie(data_csbeq_pie,
                                   wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                   colors=colors,
                                   labeldistance=0.75,
                                   radius=1.5,
                                   startangle=-36,
                                   counterclock=False,
                                   textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center')

        self.label_parameter_csbeq.setText("DOC")
        self.label_parameter_csbeq.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_parameter_csbeq.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_parameter_csbeq.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_unit_csbeq.setText("mg/l")
        self.label_unit_csbeq.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_unit_csbeq.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        #  _____________________________________         temperature
        data_temp_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_temperature.axes.pie(data_temp_pie,
                                         wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                         colors=colors,
                                         labeldistance=0.75,
                                         radius=1.5,
                                         startangle=-36,
                                         counterclock=False,
                                         rotatelabels=False,
                                         textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_temp_parameter.setText("Temperature")
        self.label_temp_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_temp_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_temp_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_temp_unit.setText("°C")
        self.label_temp_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_temp_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        #  _____________________________________ Ph

        data_ph_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow']

        self.canvas_ph.axes.pie(data_ph_pie,
                                wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                colors=colors,
                                labeldistance=0.75,
                                radius=1.5,
                                startangle=-36,
                                counterclock=False,
                                rotatelabels=False,
                                textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_ph_parameter.setText("pH")
        self.label_ph_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_ph_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_ph_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_ph_unit.setText("")
        self.label_ph_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_ph_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        data_no3_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_no3.axes.pie(data_no3_pie,
                                 wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                 colors=colors,
                                 labeldistance=0.75,
                                 radius=1.5,
                                 startangle=-36,
                                 counterclock=False,
                                 rotatelabels=False,
                                 textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_no3_parameter.setText("NO-3")
        self.label_no3_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_no3_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_no3_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_no3_unit.setText("mg/l")
        self.label_no3_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_no3_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        data_farbe_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'green']

        self.canvas_farbe.axes.pie(data_farbe_pie,
                                   wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                   colors=colors,  # normalize=True,
                                   labeldistance=0.75,
                                   radius=1.5,
                                   startangle=-36,
                                   counterclock=False,
                                   rotatelabels=False,
                                   textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_farbe_parameter.setText("Color")
        self.label_farbe_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_farbe_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_farbe_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_farbe_unit.setText("Hazen")
        self.label_farbe_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_farbe_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        #  _____________________________________ cond

        data_cod_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

        colors_cond = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_cod.axes.pie(data_cod_pie,
                                 wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                 colors=colors_cond,
                                 labeldistance=0.75,
                                 radius=1.5,
                                 startangle=-36,
                                 counterclock=False,
                                 textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_cond_parameter.setText("Condoctivity")
        self.label_cond_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_cond_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_cond_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_cond_unit.setText("µS/cm")
        self.label_cond_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_cond_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        data_afseq_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_afseq.axes.pie(data_afseq_pie,
                                   wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                   colors=colors,
                                   labeldistance=0.75,
                                   radius=1.5,
                                   startangle=-36,
                                   counterclock=False,
                                   rotatelabels=False,
                                   textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_afseq_parameter.setText("AFSeq")
        self.label_afseq_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_afseq_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_afseq_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_afseq_unit.setText("µS/cm")
        self.label_afseq_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_afseq_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        data_uv254t_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_uv254t.axes.pie(data_uv254t_pie,
                                    wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                    colors=colors,  # normalize=True,
                                    labeldistance=0.75,
                                    radius=1.5,
                                    startangle=-36,
                                    counterclock=False,
                                    rotatelabels=False,
                                    textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_uv254t_parameter.setText("UV254t")
        self.label_uv254t_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_uv254t_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_uv254t_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_uv254t_unit.setText("Abs/m")
        self.label_uv254t_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_uv254t_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        data_uv254f_pie = [0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_uv254f.axes.pie(data_uv254f_pie,
                                    wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                    colors=colors,  # normalize=True,
                                    labeldistance=0.75,
                                    radius=1.5,
                                    startangle=-36,
                                    counterclock=False,
                                    rotatelabels=False,
                                    textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_uv254f_parameter.setText("UV254f")
        self.label_uv254f_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_uv254f_parameter.setContentsMargins(20, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_uv254f_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_uv254f_unit.setText("Abs/m")
        self.label_uv254f_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_uv254f_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 20, 0)

        data_csbfeq_pie = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
        colors = ['white', 'white', 'white', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

        self.canvas_csbfeq.axes.pie(data_csbfeq_pie,
                                    wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5),
                                    colors=colors,  # normalize=True,
                                    labeldistance=0.75,
                                    radius=1.5,
                                    startangle=-36,
                                    counterclock=False,
                                    rotatelabels=False,
                                    textprops=dict(fontweight='bold', va='bottom', ha='center'))

        self.label_csbfeq_parameter.setText("CSBfeq")
        self.label_csbfeq_parameter.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.label_csbfeq_parameter.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_csbfeq_parameter.setFont(self.myFont)

        self.label_csbfeq_unit.setText("mg/l")
        self.label_csbfeq_unit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label_csbfeq_unit.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 10, 0)


        self.canvas_csbeq.draw()
        self.canvas_temperature.draw()
        self.canvas_ph.draw()
        self.canvas_no3.draw()
        self.canvas_farbe.draw()
        self.canvas_cod.draw()
        self.canvas_afseq.draw()
        self.canvas_uv254t.draw()
        self.canvas_uv254f.draw()
        self.canvas_csbfeq.draw()

        # ___________________________       adding gauge canvas and labels to its layout

        self.layout_csbeq_parameter.addWidget(self.label_parameter_csbeq)
        self.layout_csbeq_parameter.addWidget(self.label_unit_csbeq)
        self.layout_CSBeq.addLayout(self.layout_csbeq_parameter)
        self.layout_CSBeq.addWidget(self.canvas_csbeq)

        self.layout_temp_parameter.addWidget(self.label_temp_parameter)
        self.layout_temp_parameter.addWidget(self.label_temp_unit)
        self.layout_temp.addLayout(self.layout_temp_parameter)
        self.layout_temp.addWidget(self.canvas_temperature)

        self.layout_ph_parameter.addWidget(self.label_ph_parameter)
        self.layout_ph_parameter.addWidget(self.label_ph_unit)
        self.layout_ph.addLayout(self.layout_ph_parameter)
        self.layout_ph.addWidget(self.canvas_ph)

        self.layout_no3_parameter.addWidget(self.label_no3_parameter)
        self.layout_no3_parameter.addWidget(self.label_no3_unit)
        self.layout_no3.addLayout(self.layout_no3_parameter)
        self.layout_no3.addWidget(self.canvas_no3)

        self.layout_farbe_parameter.addWidget(self.label_farbe_parameter)
        self.layout_farbe_parameter.addWidget(self.label_farbe_unit)
        self.layout_farbe.addLayout(self.layout_farbe_parameter)
        self.layout_farbe.addWidget(self.canvas_farbe)

        self.layout_cond_parameter.addWidget(self.label_cond_parameter)
        self.layout_cond_parameter.addWidget(self.label_cond_unit)
        self.layout_cod.addLayout(self.layout_cond_parameter)
        self.layout_cod.addWidget(self.canvas_cod)

        self.layout_afseq_parameter.addWidget(self.label_afseq_parameter)
        self.layout_afseq_parameter.addWidget(self.label_afseq_unit)
        self.layout_afseq.addLayout(self.layout_afseq_parameter)
        self.layout_afseq.addWidget(self.canvas_afseq)

        self.layout_uv254t_parameter.addWidget(self.label_uv254t_parameter)
        self.layout_uv254t_parameter.addWidget(self.label_uv254t_unit)
        self.layout_uv254t.addLayout(self.layout_uv254t_parameter)
        self.layout_uv254t.addWidget(self.canvas_uv254t)

        self.layout_uv254f_parameter.addWidget(self.label_uv254f_parameter)
        self.layout_uv254f_parameter.addWidget(self.label_uv254f_unit)
        self.layout_uv254f.addLayout(self.layout_uv254f_parameter)
        self.layout_uv254f.addWidget(self.canvas_uv254f)
        self.layout_csbfeq_parameter.addWidget(self.label_csbfeq_parameter)
        self.layout_csbfeq_parameter.addWidget(self.label_csbfeq_unit)
        self.layout_csbfeq.addLayout(self.layout_csbfeq_parameter)
        self.layout_csbfeq.addWidget(self.canvas_csbfeq)


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tab_bar = TabBar(self)
        self.setTabBar(tab_bar)
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)


class PieCanvas(FigureCanvasQTAgg):
    def __init__(self, width=2, height=2, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi, tight_layout=True)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # self.axes.grid()
        super(PieCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        if self.count() > 0:
            size = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
            height = self.parent().size().height() / self.count()
            return QtCore.QSize(150, height)
        return super(TabBar, self).tabSizeHint(index)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)
            painter.restore()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]